# Displaying Image from Camera Roll Ionic

Tags: javascript, android, ios, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am trying to load some images from the users camera roll using Ionic 1. I am using a component which allows me to pull the location of the images and compress them so they become thumbnails for displaying.

I have got the point where I can recover the image location however the issue I'm having is displaying it in an img view tag. The component outputs the file location in a format like:

> '/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/BLAH-BLAH/tmp/B08CABBD-596C-4F1A-8905-C652C9DCBC4D^L0^001_mthumb.png'

I have tried many approaches like moving this image to anther location within the phone, renaming it to a shorter name appending the image with file:// or local:// tags and added the sanitation changes to the ionic.js. Using all of this the image back shrinks in size and doesn't show the image.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.